# flex spark buttonbar : how to determine which button in mouseOver event

Tags: apache-flex, button, mouseover, flex-spark

re: **spark.components.ButtonBar**

In the spark ButtonBar's **mouseOver** event, how do you determine which of the several buttons the mouse is hovering over?  There is, of course, no selected index at this juncture.  If it makes a difference, my ButtonBar is not defined in MXML but is instantiated in ActionScript and an ArrayList is assigned to the  dataProvider property of my ButtonBar instance.

Thanks for the  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real easy/built-in way to do this if Flex 4, and I think that's a good thing.  Instead, they give you access to the renderers via `ElementExistenceEvent.RENDERER_ADD` and `ElementExistenceEvent.RENDERER_REMOVE`, so you can look for all kinds of events on the children.  Try this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import spark.events.RendererExistenceEvent;

            protected function rendererAddHandler(event:RendererExistenceEvent):void
            {
                var element:IVisualElement = event.renderer;
                element.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, renderer_mouseMoveHandler);
            }

            protected function rendererRemoveHandler(event:RendererExistenceEvent):void
            {
                var element:IVisualElement = event.renderer;
                element.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, renderer_mouseMoveHandler);
            }

            protected function renderer_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace(event.currentTarget.label);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:ButtonBar id="buttonBar"
        rendererAdd="rendererAddHandler(event)"
        rendererRemove="rendererRemoveHandler(event)">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayList source="[one, two, three, four]"/>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:ButtonBar>
</s:Application>
```

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: Thank you, Lance, for the very helpful explanation and concise example.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `itemRollOver` event of the spark buttonbar.

Comment: Note - this event is available only at Flex 4.5 and beyond

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ListBase.html#event:itemRollOver